# custom function in google sheets with two parameters, when the first is edited the second one is executed

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to make a custom function in google sheets,
the function should have two parameters, the first one is assigned to a cell and the second one is the action you want to happen in the current cell the function is written in, but it would not get executed until the value of the first parameter is edit,
The idea is that when the value of first parameter is changed it triggers the action in the second parameter,

for example you write a function like this; =triggerAction(I6,TODAY()) , so when cell 'I6' is edited the date changes,
without this function it would edit the date when any cell is edited'

[trying using this custom function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCukn.png)

Another example is =triggerAction(I6,I6*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR")) , so when cell 'I6' is edited it gets multiplied by the live currency,
and without this function it would change the value if the rate changes and any cell is edited

I tried to write the custom function in apps script but it does not return any action

```
function triggerAction(Cell,Action) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ce = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (ce === Cell) {
    return Action
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Send strings:

```
=triggerAction("I6",I6*GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:GBPEUR"))
```

And compare them as strings:

```
  if (ce.getA1Notation() === Cell) {
```

Comment: done both but still doesn't work,

Comment: @ma Was there a error?

Comment: no, here is the new code, `function triggerAction(Cell,Action) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var ce = ss.getActiveCell();
  if (ce.getA1Notation() === Cell) {
    return Action;
  }
}`

Comment: @ma  How are you calling this function? Could you copy paste the formula?

Comment: =triggerAction(D17,TODAY()) or =triggerAction("D17",TODAY()) ,both doesn't work; without the double quates it says loading every time i edit D17 but no action is done, and with the quates it doesn't even load

Comment: @ma You probably need to debug. Log `ce.getA1Notation() === Cell` like `console.log(ce.getA1Notation())` and `console.log(Cell)`. Also use `=triggerAction("D17",TODAY(),D17)` like this. There needs to be a direct reference to D17 somewhere.

Comment: when I console.log(ce.getA1Notation()) it brings up the active cell like C10, but when I console.log(Cell) it says undefined (I think this isn't the problem because this is the ways it would come up by any function, I think the problem is with the if statement, when I edit a cell in google sheets and press enter the active cell gets one cell below so it never executes any command in the if statement, I tried to put a console in the if statement, but when I edit in google sheets it logs console.log(ce.getA1Notation()) the next cell) so if (ce.getA1Notation() === cell) doesn't match